# Is it possible to create downloadable outlook web addin

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We are trying to create an outlook web addin (using HTML & jQuery), but looking for options other than the MS Store to host the addin, like download the addin and install it from our website. Reason for this approach is that the store button/feature is disabled for many enterprises.

Tried googling, but could not find much information if this is possible. MS docs is either pointing to have the addin in MS store or let the user side load the addin (via manifest file). While second option seems to work for my scenario, but the manage addin button is not available for many enterprise users.

Comment: Sideloading is the option for the situation that you are describing. Store button won't be visible if your user don't meet requirements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins

Comment: If the administrator restricted users from adding their own apps, they won't be able to do it anyway.  You may want to provide instructions for the user to do it, if they are able, and for admins to install it if it is centrally controlled.  Note that the admin also has capability to install it for particular users or groups, so it does not need to be globally available.

Comment: The comments above are pretty accurate. The only way around the store, is to side load, or for an admin to install for all users. If admin has disabled add-in installation, then there is not a way around it.

Comment: Thanks everyone.